# Meaning of object and classes relationship

Tags: java, android, oop

A.java:

```
public class A {
    public static StartActivity startActivity;
}
```

B.java:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        A.activity = this;
    }
}
```

From the 2 java files above, I would like to ask what is the meaning of  `a.activity = this;`?
Do that mean create a new instance of activity?

Comment: Are you sure that your `**public** class StartActivity` is inside B.java? Also in class A you declared `startActivity` but in B you are using `A.activity`.

Comment: Java is case sensetive. Activity and activity are two different names in java

Comment: +1, to componsate for downvote. Seems legit to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do that mean create a new instance of activity?

No. activity is a field, not an class, and you can't create an "instance" of a variable, just of classes. All that code is doing is assigning an already existing object (the current b object) to a's static field, activity, that's all.

**Edit**
Correction, I suppose activity is also a class since you have both a type and a variable given the same name, activity? Your naming is non-standard which is confusing the issue and your question greatly. I suggest you change your question and make the naming standard and non-confusing. All types including classes, interfaces and enums should begin with an uppercase letter and all variables with a lowercase letter.

**Edit 2**
OK, after reviewing your latest code in your edited question, we see that A has a static StartActivity field, also known as a static variable, called Activity. Inside of class B's `onCreate(...)` method it assigns `this`, the reference to the current B object itself, to A's activity field. So if activity was assigned to a prior StartActivity object, that assignment has now been changed to the current B object if its `onCreate(...)` method is called.

Comment: would you mind explain the reason of that? (assigning an already existing object  to a's static field)

Comment: @user782104: the reason of what? What confuses you?

Comment: sorry for being newibe of java, i don't understand the meaning of static field

Comment: @user782104: on further review, I am confused by your post. Please see my edit above and please correct your initial post.

Comment: @user782104: please see Edit 2

Comment: thanks, that means i can change the value of activity in class A only after A.activity = this; ?

Comment: @user782104: you can change the value of A's activity field any time you want to. This is just one way it can be done.

Comment: yes, so we put A.activity = this; there because it allow the class StartActivity modify the value of StartActivity in class A